The "^" character does not interpreted as a start of line in regular expression provided to the route handler
I have one issue with express I want to use "^" as we use it in Javascript regex but unfortunately it does not work...
so here i added "^" to give pattern to the storeName path parameter::
router.get(
  "/stores/:storeName(^[a-zA-Z0-9_-][a-zA-Z0-9_-]{0,})",
  async(req, res) => {
    console.log("here");
  }
);

This route is not mach this route
"http://localhost:3000/stores/saidm"
nor this
"http://localhost:3000/stores/^saidm"
I expected the route to be matched for at least one of this paths

^ can never match in the middle of a regexp.

saidm is the :storeName. What do you expect to be matched by (^[a-zA-Z0-9_-][a-zA-Z0-9_-]{0,})?

I don't believe you can regex match parameters, only path segments. And you've already got that pattern implied by the framework. "The name of route parameters must be made up of “word characters” ([A-Za-z0-9])."_ See here. I.e., :storeName is already guaranteed to be word characters, you don't need to add a regex to it.

Oops ha ok I read the very next paragraph: _"To have more control over the exact string that can be matched by a route parameter, you can append a regular expression in parentheses ():" Hmm well OK I dunno then.

Possible duplicate. Looks like Express treats the whole URL as one regex with parenthesized groupings, and not individual regexes for each chunk. This seems to suggest that you don't need the anchor at all, and you'll still get what you want.

Based on the example in the documentation, I think the regexp is automatically anchored to match the entire route parameter. So you don't need ^ or $.
Try
router.get(
  "/stores/:storeName([\\w-]+",
  async(req, res) => {
    console.log("here");
  }
);

Note that \w matches letters, numbers, and underscore. And + is the quantifier to match 1 or more of the preceding pattern.
